# selenium webdriver getting error as with implicitlyWait was undefined

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
package mypackage;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String underConsTitle = "Under Construction: Mercury Tours";
       ((Object) ((org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) (FirefoxDriver) 
                 driver.manage1()).timeouts()).implicitlyWait(5, 
                 TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ((FirefoxDriver) driver).get(baseUrl);
        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];
        int i = 0;

        //extract the link texts of each link element
        for (WebElement e : linkElements) {
            linkTexts[i] = ((WebElement) e).getText();
            i++;
        }

        //test each link
        for (String t : linkTexts) {
           ((FirefoxDriver) driver.findElements(By.linkText(t))).click();
    if (driver.getTitle().equals(underConsTitle)) {
                System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                        + " is under construction.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                        + " is working.");
            }
            ((FirefoxDriver) driver.navigate()).back();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    private static FirefoxDriver FirefoxDriver(Object manage1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: And your question is? Please provide some context, what are you doing, what is not working, what did you try already.

Comment: What is the error message? Could you post it in its entirety?

Answer (score 1):

Actual syntax is :

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, 
>                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);

So in you case please remove 1 from below:

> ((Object) ((org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) (FirefoxDriver) 
>                    driver.manage1()).timeouts()).implicitlyWait(5, 
>                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

> ((Object) ((org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver)
>   (FirefoxDriver) 
>                driver.**manage1**()).timeouts()).implicitlyWait(5, 
>                TimeUnit.SECONDS);

manage + 1 ? I think your problem is the 1 in this line.

Do you use a IDE (like [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)), it should show where the error is.
Also do you have developers around, they should be able to help you with finding basic runtime issues.